# What is the quantified definition for proper subset

Tags: logic, elementary-set-theory

We're thinking its:

$ A \subset B \leftrightarrow \forall x [x \in A \rightarrow x \in B] \land \exists x [x \notin A \land x \in B] $

is this OK?

Thanks,

z.

Comment: Yes, that works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Brian says: Yes, that works. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Great! I was wondering, why did you include dollar{}{}{}{}{}{}dollar in your answer?

Comment: An answer has to contain some minimum number of characters before the system will accept it. Since my first attempt to submit it had too few characters, I added some do-nothing TeX code to mollify the server.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the axiom of extensionality to make a simpler definition: $$A\subsetneq B =_\mathrm{def} (\forall x\in A. x\in B)\land \lnot(A=B).$$

This is, of course, equivalent to yours.